# .NET 6 reading standard output blocks on Linux

Tags: .net, linux, process

I have a .NET 6 process **prog1** which starts a .NET 6 process **prog2**, redirects its standard output and waits for all output. **prog2** starts a .NET 6 process **prog3** without redirecting its output and shuts down. **prog3** runs forever.

The code looks like this:

```cs
// prog1:
using System.Diagnostics;

var process = new Process
{
    StartInfo =
    {
        FileName = "prog2",
        RedirectStandardOutput = true,
        UseShellExecute = false
    }
};
process.Start();
process.WaitForExit();

Console.WriteLine(process.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd());

// prog2:
using System.Diagnostics;

using var process = new Process
{
    StartInfo =
    {
        FileName = "prog3",
        UseShellExecute = true
    }
};
process.Start();

// prog3:
Thread.Sleep(Timeout.Infinite);
```

This works just fine on Windows, but on Linux **prog1** hangs forever in the line

```cs
Console.WriteLine(process.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd());
```

and waits for **prog3** to finish.

AFAIK .NET does already duplication of stdout file descriptors after the fork, so **prog3** should not affect **prog1**.
Is this a bug? Or am I missing something in my implementation?